# Problems with GlassFish using IntelliJ, deploy is not available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I've started using GlassFish 4.1.1 with IntelliJ and tried created a new J2EE project.

The only thing I modified was the output message written out by the facelet.

Now deploying and thus connecting to the server doesn't seem to work.

The message:

```
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
[2016-04-18 10:30:58,648] Artifact FirstEE:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:459)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:326)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:99)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:192)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:228)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:124)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)

Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
"C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" stop-domain --domaindir "C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\
```

---

What I tried out:

- Checking for any process listening to port 4848, there's none
- deleted the standard domain `domain1` and tried to create a new one, failed because the command `asadmin` is unknown.
- added "asadmin" file from glassfish's directory to the PATH variable, still unknown.
- Reinstalling GlassFish
- GlassFish's and IntelliJ's version are are up to date

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was pretty **trivial**... Just had to run my IDE as an administrator because elseway IntelliJ had no access to the server log file and thus couldn't make neccessary changes in it.

> Be sure to check out the **other solutions** I named in my questions though...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to start IntelliJ with sudo permission?