# Intellij - Failed to start project in external drive: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, filesystems, jetty

I could run my [[image]jetty](/questions/tagged/jetty) project up to a few days ago with [[image]intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea), but since yesterday, when I press `run` / `debug` I get:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\workspace_professional\01_clients\my_client\workspace\branch_develop
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.getInputStream(PathResource.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SpnegoLoginService.doStart(SpnegoLoginService.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.container.JettyApplicationContainer.startServer(JettyApplicationContainer.java:339)
    at com.container.JettyApplicationContainer.launch(JettyApplicationContainer.java:57)
    at com.bootstrap.Bootstrap.startApplication(Bootstrap.java:201)
    at com.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:77)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run(WrapperManager.java:4241)
```

The project workspace is stored onto an external encrypted drive.

---

What I have tried so far:

- Start `IntelliJ` as Administrator
- Unchecked the `Read-Only` property under `Properties` but it seems to *check* back when I reopen the `Properties` tab (both for the drive root and the folder marked in the stacktrace)
- Give all permissions for the entire drive to all users / groups under `Properties > Security`
- Try the replace child object permissions with entries from `D:\` (under `Properties > Security > Advanced` but I get the error:

[image: Error applying security info]

---

A few threads from SO about this topic, but the solutions don't work for me:

- [AccessDeniedException while using Files.move()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988210/java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-while-using-files-move)
- [Problems with GlassFish using IntelliJ, deploy is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704670/problems-with-glassfish-using-intellij-deploy-is-not-available)
- [java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when trying to write to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670576/getting-java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-when-trying-to-write-to-a-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Tools used are:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.5087.20, built on May 17, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

---

Has anyone had this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, this has nothing to do with permissions whatsoever...

When `git-pulling`, a property was overridden to be empty (`""`) instead of an actual path (`"/bla.file"`), thus the [[image]jetty](/questions/tagged/jetty) launcher could not correctly open a file and triggered a

```
AccessDeniedException: D:\workspace_professional\01_clients\my_client\workspace\branch_develop
```

With the property set, it would have read:

```
D:\workspace_professional\01_clients\my_client\workspace\branch_develop\bla.file
```

Basically, the solutions is the same as [this one linked in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673369/8524301).